# Is there a with() method inside ImmutableMap?

Tags: java, guava, immutable-collections

I am watching the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM) and find that we can initialize the ImmutableMap using the with() method. See below:

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer>
    ENGLISH_TO_INT = ImmutableMap
        .with("four", 4)
        .with("eight", 8)
        .with("fifteen", 15)
        .with("sixteen", 16)
        .with("twenty-three", 23)
        .with("forty-two", 42)
        .build();
```

However, when I check the API of ImmutableMap, I didn't find a with() method. Is that method been deprecated?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code

Comment: Deprecated methods still exist. Are you sure they were talking about Guava? What version?

Comment: In exactly the way you wrote it, it can't work as the first use of `with` requires a `static` method and for it all to work it mustn't be `static`. That's why the `builder()` call is needed. Note also that there is an `of` method accepting up to 4 pairs.

Comment: I feel I am to blame for not figuring out how to add annotations to the video to explain "this s*** is old, do this instead".

Comment: Cool, thanks, @KevinBourrillion , it's good to get the response from the presenter :-) And btw, the UniqueList is also not released, right? Because LinkedHashSet is there in Java.

Comment: Yeah, it never really caught on and we need to do some study to see whether it's worth it. If you don't need mutation, then ImmutableSet and its asList() view serve the very same purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing they deprecated it in favor of explicitly creating a builder, and using `put` to mirror the method of the same name on a `Map`. I am looking at the [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReleaseHistory), but I haven't found anything explicit, yet. That video is old, and Guava has a much more recent version.

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), it has been there since `version 2.0`, when it was merged from [google-collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). Taking a closer look at the video shows that they are demonstrating with version `0.9`.

Looking at the [releases of google-collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/wiki/Releases), I don't see any listed changes and I don't see it in any of the Javadoc, so I am guessing it didn't make it into any of the official releases.

If you need to construct an `ImmutableMap` with a bunch of entries, you can use the `builder()` call. There are also several `of()` methods that can generate maps of a limited size (I think 5?).

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer>
    ENGLISH_TO_INT = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
    .put("four", 4)
    .put("eight", 8)
    .put("fifteen", 15)
    .put("sixteen", 16)
    .put("twenty-three", 23)
    .put("forty-two", 42)
    .build();
```

Comment: @injoy I don't think it made it into any of the releases. I added some more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [of() method](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28K,%20V%29)

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> ENGLISH_TO_INT =
ImmutableMap.of("four", 4, "eight", 8);
```